# VBA to read or "catch" a dialog box

Tags: excel, vba, automationanywhere

[image]

Is there a way to catch or read the dialog written on an alert? This has been showing sometimes during the execution and I can't catch it with `On Error`

I also tried using `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` in the BeforeSave sub but it's still appearing.

My excel VBA workbook is run by an Automation Anywhere bot so I can't just make sure that I have enough space. I just need to handle this alert that pops up when the space is full.

BTW, I also tried checking the disk/folder space first using a vba code but it doesn't work on a shared drive path. It works on a local though.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do what you're trying to do. The task you're attempting to automate has failed, and rather than fixing the issue in the first place, you want to throw away the notice of that failure and let the automation continue? That doesn't make any sense. Why don't you just save the workbook in a place that will always have enough space instead? Sticking your head in the sand and ignoring the problem doesn't make any sense. If the completion of the task isn't important, why do it at all?

Comment: Because it is an unattended bot and if I leave it like that, then the bot would just stop mid-running. I am always unsure of how big the files that will be saved. Say the first batch of generating and saving workbooks may be just enough for the folder storage but the second batch may be too big. I would like to handle the error and inform the person who ran the tool that the reason why their process failed is because there is not enough space.